# Is there any method to use an automatic word wrap in equations?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, equations

In common words, the word wrap is done automatically.
But in the equations, it doesn't work.
Actually, I am making some presentation material using beamer in Latex.

Is there any way to make word wrap automatically?
I hope the first line is left align, simultaneously, second line is right align

My code is like the following:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=0, t]{The \textbf{\textit{DP}} Algorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \begin{proof}

            \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumi}{4}
            \item Since $\pi^k=\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)$,
            \begin{align*}
                J_k^*(x_k) &= \min_{\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)} \underset{w_k, \cdots, w_{N-1}}{E}
                \left\{ g_k(x_k, \mu_k(x_k), w_k) + g_N(x_N) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{N-1} g_i(x_i, \mu_i(x_i), w_i)\right\}\\
                &= 123
            \end{align*}
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{proof}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

[image: 1212121]

Comment: Equations do no automatic linebreaks

Comment: Look at the `breqn` package

Comment: The esthetics of displayed equations do not automate well.  For example, you would probably like to have the broken part align with the left brace.  Also \left \right won't work over multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply to show how to reformat the equation with as little effort as possible.  Copy the line to be broken.  Use `\right.` or `\left.` to balance an otherwise unmatched `\left` or `\right`.  Use `\hphantom` to preserve spacing, and `\vphantom` to preserve the `\left ... \right` size.

Note, the additional `\qquad` is to compensate for the missing `=` and `\{`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=0, t]{The \textbf{\textit{DP}} Algorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \begin{proof}

            \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumi}{4}
            \item Since $\pi^k=\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)$,
            \begin{align*}
                J_k^*(x_k) &= \min_{\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)} \underset{w_k, \cdots, w_{N-1}}{E}
                \left\{ g_k(x_k, \mu_k(x_k), w_k) + g_N(x_N) \vphantom{+ \sum_{i=k+1}^{N-1} g_i(x_i, \mu_i(x_i), w_i)}\right.\\
                &\qquad \hphantom{\min_{\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)} \underset{w_k, \cdots, w_{N-1}}{E}}
                \left. \vphantom{g_k(x_k, \mu_k(x_k), w_k) + g_N(x_N)} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{N-1} g_i(x_i, \mu_i(x_i), w_i)\right\}\\
                &= 123
            \end{align*}
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{proof}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `breqn` package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,breqn,lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{frame}[shrink=0, t]{The \textbf{\textit{DP}} Algorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \begin{proof}

            \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumi}{4}
            \item Since $\pi^k=\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)$,
            \begin{dmath*}
                J_k^*(x_k) = \min_{\left(\mu_k, \pi^{k+1}\right)} \underset{w_k, \cdots, w_{N-1}}{E}
                \left\{ g_k(x_k, \mu_k(x_k), w_k) + g_N(x_N) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{N-1} g_i(x_i, \mu_i(x_i), w_i)\right\}\\
                = 123
            \end{dmath*}
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{proof}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, in mine, it does not work well. I made with h(v)phantom. I know your solution is not wrong, just my skill lacks in using your solution. T.T